# Does cubic equation have any integer solution for X if all constants are integers

Tags: cubics

I'm stuck with the following equation:

$$x^3 + a \cdot x^2 + b \cdot x + c = d $$
$$ x, a, b, c, d > 1,$$
$$ x < d $$
$$ a < d $$
$$ b < d $$
$$ c < d $$

$$ x, a, b, c, d \in \Bbb{Z} $$

We need to proof that this equation hasn't got any integers solutions for $x$.

Tried several times, but didn't find any approach. Will be happy for hints.

Comment: You list $b$ among your conditions, but it doesn't appear in the equation.

Comment: If $a=c=1$ and $d=4$, then the equation has a positive integer solution $x=1$.

Comment: Sorry, fixed typo

Comment: Your assertion isn't true.  You can pick any positive integers you want for $x, a, b, c$ and then $d$ will be a positive integer, so that gives you and equation for which $x$ is a positive integer solution.

Comment: (For the revised question) If $ a=b=c=2$ and $d=22$, then the equation has a positive integer solution $x=2$.